# font sharp effect not supported

Tags: php, html, css, dreamweaver

We are making a website using dreamweaver (html, php, javascript, css...) and using mainly a Myriad font. Font is properly attached but in photoshop there is a text parameter called "Sharp" that cannot be applied. How to do it? Thank you

Comment: Is this a Photoshop question or a HTML question? You need to add way more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you can't. Your options for font styles in HTML are basically limited to bold, italic and underlining. You should also be using web-safe fonts as a lot of your visitors are unlikely to have Myriad installed (assuming this is not for an internal site where you control the users machines).

Have a read of this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_typography#Web-safe_fonts

Answer (score 0):

You can't really control this in html/css...

If you really must, you could use sIfr,http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/sifr/, but this is considered bad practice nowadays.

There are some hacks, but never ones that are really consistent accross browsers. For example

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px transparent;
```

is supposed to smooth your text.